# Google services links in Chrome new tab missing

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines, google-search

After making some changes to default search engines in chrome, on new tab I lost the bar in right top corner with direct links to G+, Gmail, Google apps drop-down list, notifications and account. Also cannot find initial Google search engine with this feature.

How to bring back this function to new tab in Google chrome?

Comment: Did you try undoing the changes you made?

Comment: Under default search engines I have 4 Google engines, by switching to any of them I cannot bring it back. I don't know witch exactly were the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache from browser and check. Also  Restore settings to their original defaults from settings page and check

Comment: Thanks, Restore setting helped to get it back. And here it is:

{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:bookmarkBarPinned}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:omniboxStartMarginParameter}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}